# Meteor collection get last document of each selection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Currently I use the following find query to get the latest document of a certain ID

```
Conditions.find({
                        caveId: caveId
                    },
                    {
                        sort: {diveDate:-1},
                        limit: 1,
                        fields: {caveId: 1, "visibility.visibility":1, diveDate: 1}
                    });
```

How can I use the same using multiple ids with $in for example

I tried it with the following query. The problem is that it will limit the documents to 1 for all the found caveIds. But it should set the limit for each different caveId.

```
Conditions.find({
                        caveId: {$in: caveIds}
                    },
                    {
                        sort: {diveDate:-1},
                        limit: 1,
                        fields: {caveId: 1, "visibility.visibility":1, diveDate: 1}
                    });
```

One solution I came up with is using the aggregate functionality.

```
var conditionIds = Conditions.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": { caveId: {"$in": caveIds}}},
            {
                $group:
                    {
                        _id: "$caveId",
                        conditionId: {$last: "$_id"},
                        diveDate: { $last: "$diveDate" }
                    }
                }
        ]
    ).map(function(child) { return child.conditionId});

    var conditions = Conditions.find({
                        _id: {$in: conditionIds}
                    },
                    {
                        fields: {caveId: 1, "visibility.visibility":1, diveDate: 1}
                    });
```

Comment: I think you need to look into using https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `$in` here as noted. You could solve this problem by looping through the caveIds and running the query on each caveId individually.

Answer (score 0):

you're basically looking at a join query here: you need all caveIds and then lookup last for each.

This is a problem of database schema/denormalization in my opinion: (but this is only an opinion!):

You could as mentioned here, lookup all `caveIds` and then run the single query for each, every single time you need to look up last dives.

However I think you are much better off recording/updating the last dive inside your `cave` document, and then lookup all caveIds of interest pulling only the `lastDive` field.

That will give you immediately what you need, rather than going through expensive search/sort queries. This is at the expense of maintaining that field in the document, but it sounds like it should be fairly trivial as you only need to update the one field when a new event occurs.

Comment: Hi. I have not thought about that solution actually of updating the cave document with the lastDive date. That would probably make it a lot simpler.  I have come across a solution using aggregate functionality to sort and group as you mentioned. It does work but am not quite sure how expensive it is on performance. I added the code to my question.